# Solve the following system of 3 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need help solving this system of equations in order to prepare for my math exam. I've tried all the ways I know but I've only managed to find false solutions...

\begin{cases}
y+2xz=0\\
x+4yz=0\\
x^2+2y^2-2=0
\end{cases}

[Here are the correct solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2B2*x*z%3D0%3Bx%2B4*y*z%3D0%3Bx%5E2%2B2*y%5E2-2%3D0)

Comment: **Hint:** From the first equation, solve for $z$, substitute into second equation and simplify. Now using that new equation and the third, life is easy!

Answer (score 0):

The first equation gives $y^2-2xyz=0.$ The second equation gives $x^2+4xyz.$ We then derive $x^2=2y^2.$

From $x^2+2y^2-2=0$ we get $y^2=2$, hence $y= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From first and second equation:
$$
0=x+4yz=x+4(-2xz)z=x(1-8z^2)
$$
Then either $x=0$ (which implies $y=0$ and contradicts the last equation) or $8z^2=1$. Then it is sufficient to replace $y=-2xz$ into the last one, to obtain
$$
0=x^2+2y^2-2=x^2+2(-2xz)^2-2=x^2(1+8z^2)-2=2(x^2-1)
$$
Substitute $x=\pm 1$ and get the wanted solutions.